# How to turn String into UnityEngine.Sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So inside my "SpriteChanger" script, I have two sprites: "Happy" and "Sad". In my "GameControl" script, I have a string "currentMood" which starts out as "Happy". But then I have a public void to change the "currentMood" into "Sad".
Now in the SpriteChanger script, I put this.GetComponent ().sprite = which works when I manually put in the name of the sprite.

However, I do not want to have a bajillion of those if I had a lot of sprites I need to switch to. I need a way to have this.GetComponent ().sprite = take the literal input of "currentMood". But Unity keeps saying that it cannot implicitly convert String to UnityEngine.Sprite.

Here's the code:

```
GameControl{

 public string currentMood = "Happy";
 public void changeMood () {
     currentMood = "Sad";
 }
 /some function that calls changeMood somewhere here/
} ..

.
SpriteChanger {

 public Sprite Happy;
 public Sprite Sad;
 /*and a buncha other sprites*/
 public void changeMood () {
     this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = GameControl.instance.currentMood)
 }
}
```

Comment: Instead of strings rather use an [`enum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum) this is saver against typos and also better performance wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t use strings in these situations. It is always better to use an integer or something else. A string takes 8 bytes for each character, but an integer can store any number near the billions with only 4 bytes. This is a much better way of storing values. You could change the part in the first script to:

```cs
GameControl{

 public int currentMood = 0;//happy
 public void changeMood () {
     currentMood = 1;//sad
 }
 //some function that calls changeMood somewhere here
}
```

```cs
SpriteChanger {

 public Sprite CurrentSprite;
 public Sprite Happy;
 public Sprite Sad;
 /*and a buncha other sprites*/
 public void changeMood () {
     switch (GameControl.instance.currentMood)
     {
         case 0:
            CurrentSprite = Happy;
            break;
         case 1:
            CurrentSprite = Sad;
            break;
         ...//more cases
         default:
            Debug.Log(“Unknown case”);
            break;
     }
     this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = CurrentSprite;
 }
}
```

Here, we use a switch statement. It is basically the same thing as an if statement, just we use them in these cases. The problem you were getting with converting a string to a sprite is that strings are just a variable like an integer. The way we write code is much more different to the computer. Names are just what we call the variable. It is what we use to reference that value. A name is not a string, though. So we cannot use variables with a string for their name.

What is a [switch?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch)

Comment: Even better, use an `enum`, it is just as efficient as a number and it can have meaningful names.

Comment: True, I just don’t use them as much, and can’t provide a good example if I don’t really understand them.